# How to catch backslash keypress?

Tags: python, scripting, uv, shortcut

I want make actions on key press in UV Editor Blender, how to catch this event?

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Your question is being flagged as low quality due to it's length. Could you add some information about what you are doing/have tried already? (Could you use an operator with a shortcut assigned?)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [addon tutorial](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_tutorial_addon.html#keymap) that covers keymaps.

```
# store keymaps here to access after registration
addon_keymaps = []

def register():

    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Mode', space_type='EMPTY')

    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(ObjectCursorArray.bl_idname, 'SPACE', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=True)
    kmi.properties.total = 4

    addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))


def unregister():

    # handle the keymap
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()
```

There are several addons that can be viewed as examples as well.

[Material Utils](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/space_view3d_materials_utils.py) is one of them -

```
kc = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
if kc:
    km = kc.keymaps.new(name="3D View", space_type="VIEW_3D")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu', 'Q', 'PRESS')
    kmi.properties.name = "VIEW3D_MT_master_material"
```